# Bug when editing comments

Tags: bug, comments, edits, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

When I add a comment and after that I edit it, the cursor goes to the upper left corner of the first comment and the page is not longer usable:

[image: Edited comment]

I am using Internet Explorer. The same problem I can see in MS Edge.

Comment: What version of IE? Hopefully not IE6. Anyway no repro with Chrome latest version.

Comment: No sometimes IE9 and sometimes IE11. with both i have the same problem.

Comment: IE9 is not supported by Stack Exchange, and can't repro with IE11. Something on your end is probably broken, first thing I would check is userscripts/browser extensions that mess with the DOM.

Comment: I repro this on IE11 as well, sometimes. Just click on any area that doesn't have a click handler and you're good to go....

Comment: Thanks for downvote. I try to help making stackoverflow better.